# Khajit dawnstar chest not working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to do the Khajit dawnstar chest loop, but for the Dark Brotherhood's quest line I've killed two khajits of the trading caravan in dawnstar.
Now they don't spawn in dawnstar anymore, but their body's are still on the floor.
Pls help :)

Comment: are you on a pc? if so resurrecting them with console commands might fix the problem

Comment: yes I am, where can I find the command to do that?

Comment: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim) is a nice page. to summarize though, to resurrect them, use the ` key to open the console, then type resurrect "idnumber" where the idnumber is the idnumber of the npc you are trying to resurrect. alternately you can just click on the body with the mouse when the console is open (make sure the body is selected and not something else) then just type resurrect and push enter. if this works, i can make this an answer

Comment: it seems to have worked, the people walked away and the khajit spawned again. Thanks

Comment: no problem. made it into an answer that you can accept so others who have this problem know that it worked.

Comment: The what loop? Care to explain what it is? Now I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since my suggestions in the comment seemed to have fixed the problem, i'll make it an answer.

using the resurrect command from the console on pc can fix this. fill list of console commands can be found [here.](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim))
to summarize the needed info though, to resurrect them, use the ` key to open the console, then type resurrect "idnumber" where the idnumber is the idnumber of the npc you are trying to resurrect. alternately you can just click on the body with the mouse when the console is open (make sure the body is selected and not something else) then just type resurrect and push enter

Comment: Note that resurrect does not work that well in skyrim. Various scripts activate when a NPC dies (such as the creation of tombstones). This breaks in various ways when you use resurrect. Search for the command on this wiki: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console (don't use the wikia one, it contains less information than uesp).